# combining C\C++ translation units state?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a main.c file which includes a guarded (#ifndef...) c header, called mydefinitions.h.

In the header i declare an extern function, lets call it CppMain, to which i then call from the main.c file.

The CppMain function is defined in cppmain.cpp file which includes the (guarded) mydefinitions.h file as an extern "C" header.

The problem i am encountering is that a certain function, INIT_Pfn, which is declared and defined in the mydefinitions.h file is being defined multiple times (compiler argues multiple definitions of said method).

to my understanding the compiler is processing cppmain.cpp as a result of the definition of the said extern CppMain function but reprocess the mydefinitions.h since it is outside the scope of main.c and therefore the guard (#ifndef...) is being reinitialized - which, to me, is totally reasonable.

The main gist of the issue is that i'm trying to implement some logic in C++ as opposed to doing it all in C, but to keep the global scope\state of the main.c program translation.

Is there any way to avoid taking out the INIT_Pfn out of the mydefinitions.h file? Any other way you might think of implementing this solution without affecting mydefinitions.h?
the file also defines a global variable which has dependencies all over the source...

EDITTED (added code snippets):

mydefinitions.h:

```
#ifndef MyDefinitions
#define MyDefinitions

unsigned int GLOBAL_STATE = 0;
extern void CppMain();

#endif // !MyDefinitions
```

MyCPPFile.cpp:

```
#ifndef MyCPPFile
#define MyCPPFile

extern "C" {
#include "mydefinitions.h"
}

extern "C" void CppMain()
{
    // cpp code here
}
#endif // !MyCPPFile
```

main.c file:

```
#include "mydefinitions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CppMain();
}
```

Comment: Can you put this as a code example please? Reduce it down to a pithy example showing only your issue. We like code ;) (but don't want to see all your source - just the relevant bits!)

Comment: Either make it `static` so it has internal linkage, or make it `inline`.

Comment: But yes, correctly using `extern "C"` will allow you to call procedural C++ code from C code.

Comment: Why are you defining functions in a header? That is simply not something you should do unless they are `static inline`.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys, already learn a few things(!), but still - is there a way for this to be done without changing the header file?
also would like to add that taking the definition for the method out of the header is a good tip but i am working on a rather unstable environment

Comment: @Lundin even if i take the definition for the method out, wont the global variable (unstatic non internal to translation unit) be defined again? wont this cause ambiguity or even some override/create another variable?

Comment: Terminology note: your header does not *define* any function or method.  It *declares* one.  The distinction applies to both functions and variables, though it manifests a bit differently for the two kinds of entities.  For functions, a definition is a declaration that includes the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that every object file compiled from source contains both the integer `GLOBAL_STATE` as well as a runtime initialiser for it.  You only need it *defined* once.

In the header file, declare the variable `extern`:

```
extern unsigned int GLOBAL_STATE;
```

In your main C file, define it:

```
unsigned int GLOBAL_STATE = 0;
```

You don't need the `#define MyCPPFile` malarky in the CPP file.

Comment: in the end i got around to the same solution, also cpp file started as header
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the function is written in common subset of C and C++, then you could declare the function static inline and it should work.

The variable has to be defined elsewhere or has to be static since C doesn't have inline variables.